# Probability of 3 people being born on consecutive days of the week

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I started studying probabilities and I'm stuck trying to find the probability of 3 randomly chosen people on the street being born on consecutive days of the week (for example: Mon, Tue, Wed). This is what I tried to do:

> First I manually wrote all the possible ways of having consecutive triples of days and found out there are 7 cases, then there are 7^3 possible ways of the 3 people having their birthdays in a week so the probability would be **7/7^3 = 0.02** (possitive cases / total cases)

But i know that approach won't work on bigger problems (like 3 consecutive days on a year) so I tried using combinatorics to find the positive cases using the following procedure:

> The 1st person has the possibility of being born in any day of the week (7 cases) 
> The 2nd one must be born the day after or the day before the 1st one (2 cases) 
>  The 3rd also has 2 options depending of what the 2nd one chose (2 cases). 
>  This way there are **7x2x2 = 28** possible arrangement but i then divide that by 3! = 6 because i don't care about the order so Mon,Tue,Wed is the same as Wed,Mon,Tue in this case. 
> But I obtain a different answer than before **(28/6) / 7^3 = 0.09** and having 28/6 possible cases doesn't make any sense.

So I wanted to know what I'm missing on the combinatorics approach, idk if I am missing cases or what is wrong. 
Also sorry if i wrote too much and i appreciate all of your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both answers are wrong. In the first one, you should account for the ordering in the numerator because you did in the denominator (i.e. $7^3$ already has the ordering). So, the correct answer is $7\times 3! / 7^3=6/49$. By the way, this logic would work just fine in regular years (i.e. no leap year), and it is a combinatorics approach, too.